# Как сделать чтоб длинный текст вмещался в TextField?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield

Сделал TextField друго размера по коду, но когда ввожу данные текст не продлевается вниз по строчкам. а идет по этой же линии и нечего не видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextField` всегда в одну строку. Для текста в несколько строк используйте `UITextView`.